# How to configure the route procurement on odoo 11?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

right now i'm setting up the inventory part on odoo 11, just a short, when i use a product that will be buy at the sale order, so when i confirm I have this error message in sale order:

> no procurement rule was found. Check the configuration of your routes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have properly setup the database. This is mostly due to an issue with your setup. Check you have setup routes properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have setup your warehouse and location correctly, If you are using any sub location mention the type of location correctly. If Advanced routing is enabled setup your routes according to your needs.